# How configure EventBusServiceBus with Azure Service Bus?

Tags: c#, asp.net, azureservicebus, event-bus

I need to configure a Library `EventBusServiceBus`, but searching did not found any sample. Please, I need examples, how to configure a connection with `EventBusServiceBus` using appSettings.json

Comment: It will help if you provide a reference or a link to `EventBusServiceBus`.

Comment: This https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/standard/microservices-architecture/multi-container-microservice-net-applications/integration-event-based-microservice-communications

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a ".NET Microservices: Architecture for Containerized .NET Applications" e-book, aka  eShopOnContainers with code on [GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnContainers).

[`EventBusServiceBus`](https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnContainers/blob/dev/src/BuildingBlocks/EventBus/EventBusServiceBus/EventBusServiceBus.cs) should receive an implementation of `IServiceBusPersisterConnection`. Which is implemented with `DefaultServiceBusPersisterConnection`, which subsequently depends on Azure Service Bus `ServiceBusConnectionStringBuilder` to be created and registered in the services. An example would be one of the services configurations such as Ordering service [here](https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnContainers/blob/167bb167ff94a7b15e9b4eaaee697ffbecebc8c4/src/Services/Ordering/Ordering.BackgroundTasks/Startup.cs#L50).

In `appsettings.json` you'll have to define the following settings:

- `AzureServiceBusEnabled` set to `true`
- `EventBusConnection` set to the Azure Service Bus connection string

Comment: When configure EventBus, I have this error: System.ArgumentException: 'The argument is null or white space.' . following data comes null: EntityPath, SasToken

Comment: How do you construct `ServiceBusConnectionStringBuilder`?

Comment: When you initialize `DefaultServiveBusPersisterConnection` you need to provide a `SerciveBusConnectionStringBuilder` and pass it in. Have you looked at the code I pointed you to [here](https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnContainers/blob/167bb167ff94a7b15e9b4eaaee697ffbecebc8c4/src/Services/Ordering/Ordering.BackgroundTasks/Startup.cs#L59)?

Comment: Look my startup, I belive that all right https://ghostbin.com/paste/vgdkn

Comment: The code instantiates a `TopicClient` using connection string builder. `EntityPath` in the connection string is not defined, therefore you get the exception. Also, change the SasKey of your connection string as it's now publicly exposed... Tip: in the future, adding a link/permalink to the code in question helps. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

When using the eShopOnContainers application, Service Bus is not properly implemented in the GIT repo.

You are missing entityPath parameter in your connection string. You will have to first create a Topic in Azure Service Bus. Set the entityPath= name of your topic in Azure Service Bus. In Azure Service Bus, also create a Subscription for this Topic. You will need to configure this in the appsettings.json file. Set the value of the subscriptionClientName in appsettings file to the name of the Subscription you just created.